# Inline divs are not lining up in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's my understanding that simply adding `display:inline` to divs with a relative position will line them up (left to right), somewhat like `float:left`. I've tried both approaches but they haven't worked.

Below is an example of my last attempt, using inline displaying. I want all three segments to line up from left to right, but they're displaying just like unstyled divs.

```js
function showProfile() {
  var profile = document.getElementById('userprofile');
  profile.style.opacity = 0.8;
  var profileImage = document.getElementById('userimage');
  profileImage.style.opacity = 0.8;
}
```

```css
.profile {
  top: 68px;
  background-color: #424755;
  color: #dddddd;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  font: 16px"Tahoma";
}
.miniProfileImage {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.miniBioSegment {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile" id="userprofile">
  <div class="miniBioSegment">
    <img class="miniProfileImage" id="userimage" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000088/ffffff.png&text=Profile+image">
  </div>
  <div id="miniBio" class="miniBioSegment">
    This is basic information about this person that you clicked.
  </div>
  <div id="miniQuote" class="miniBioSegment">
    This is a tag line from the person that you clicked.
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="showProfile()">View Profile</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use inline-block instead of inline for more control. I used a width of 33%-2px because the browser rounds the div's size up therefore leading to overflowing. Your 5px margins weren't helping with the sum either.

```js
function showProfile() {
  var profile = document.getElementById('userprofile');
  profile.style.opacity = 0.8;
  var profileImage = document.getElementById('userimage');
  profileImage.style.opacity = 0.8;
}
```

```css
.profile {
  top: 68px;
  background-color: #424755;
  color: #dddddd;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  font: 16px"Tahoma";
}
.miniProfileImage {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.miniBioSegment{
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(33% - 2px);
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile" id="userprofile">
  <div class="miniBioSegment">
    <img class="miniProfileImage" id="userimage" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000088/ffffff.png&text=Profile+image">
  </div>
  <div id="miniBio" class="miniBioSegment">
    This is basic information about this person that you clicked.
  </div>
  <div id="miniQuote" class="miniBioSegment">
    This is a tag line from the person that you clicked.
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="showProfile()">View Profile</button>
```

Comment: Is CSS calc() widely supported? I am taking your advice and using padding rather than margins.

Comment: It's supported in IE10+ and major browsers. You can use width 32% instead if you'd like to avoid using calc.

Comment: I'm not sure why I can't use 50% instead of 42% but this works for me: #divLeft{display:inline-block;width:104px;} #divMiddle{display:inline-block;width: calc(42% - 52px);} #divRight{display: inline-block;width:calc(42% - 52px);}

Answer (score 1):

CSS should target the ID's and use `float:left`.  See example

```css
    .profile {
      top: 68px;
      background-color: #424755;
      color: #dddddd;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 50px;
      position: fixed;
      font: 16px"Tahoma";
      
    }
    .miniProfileImage {
      float:left;
      max-width: 33%;
      height: 100px;
    }
    #miniBio {
      float:left;
      margin-right: 5px;
      width: 33%;
    }
    #miniQuote {
      float:left;
      margin-right: 5px;
      width: 33%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="profile" id="userprofile">
      <div class="miniBioSegment">
        <img class="miniProfileImage" id="userimage" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000088/ffffff.png&text=Profile+image">
      </div>
      <div id="miniBio" class="miniBioSegment">
        This is basic information about this person that you clicked.
      </div>
      <div id="miniQuote" class="miniBioSegment">
        This is a tag line from the person that you clicked.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ron. That worked, great, but it's a shame that the alignment can't happen at the class level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm asking myself, why do you have `position:absolute;`?

To make it work, I have just added `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` to the `.profile`class.

Remove the position, and try adding the last two lines.

See example here: http://sandbox.clickadelic.de/demos/lineup.html

Comment: I don't see any absolute positioning in my CSS, unless you mean fixed? I need it to be fixed because I want it to stay near the top of a page.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I ment fixed. mybad. ok - it should work the way I suggested either way.

Comment: No worries, I think they're very similar anyway. @Ron Royston's solution worked well, but I might try flex because I want a fixed-flex-flex pattern (the leftmost div is fixed)

Answer (score 1):

With the divs set to `display: inline;` they will only line up horizontally if the total length of the divs does not exceed the container's width.

And `width`, `height` of inline elements is ignored, you should use `display: inline-block;` instead. The wrapping behavior is the same as above.

Also browser renders whitespace among inline* elements, which is about 4px, see [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/483779) for more details.

In your example, there are 3 divs, if you want them to be equal width, you can do:

```
.profile {
  font-size: 0; /*remove whitespace*/
  background: silver;
}
.miniBioSegment {
  font-size: 16px; /*reset font-size*/
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; /*vertical alignment*/
  width: 33.3333%;
}
```

However, the image object in the first div is set to 100px, I think you would prefer that div to be the same width too, and each one takes 50% of the rest space for other two divs. Examples:

### 1. Inline block

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0msvLLy/)**

```
.profile {
  font-size: 0;
  background: silver;
}
.miniBioSegment {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
}
#miniBio, #miniQuote {
  width: calc((100% - 100px) / 2);
}
.miniProfileImage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

### 2. Float

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jj1n7v9g/)**

```
.profile {
  background: silver;
}
.profile:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.miniBioSegment {
  float: left;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
}
#miniBio, #miniQuote {
  width: calc((100% - 100px) / 2);
}
.miniProfileImage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

### 3. CSS table

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9d99s3qj/)**

```
.profile {
  background: silver;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.miniBioSegment {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
#miniBio, #miniQuote {
  width: 50%;
}
.miniProfileImage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

### 4. Flexbox

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6eqza2v5/)**

```
.profile {
  background: silver;
  display: flex;
}
.miniBioSegment {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
#miniBio, #miniQuote {
  flex: 1;
}
.miniProfileImage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```